# errors when static and when not static (specific)

Tags: java, android, static, static-methods

I know the title doesn't say much, but I have a pretty specific problem that is difficult to describe:

I'm making an android app with Android Studio, and for one activity I have a list where the values that are stored in a json file will go.

For getting these values I use another class with a get() method which returns the values in an arraylist. The problem is that the IDE says 2 contrary statements: in the activity class it says that the get() method has to be static and in the other class it says that the get() method can't be static.

This is the code:

CompanySelector.java (the activity)

```
public class CompanySelector extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> companyList = CompanyStorage.get();
}
```

==> here it gives an error in CompanyStorage.get() and says that get() should be static.

CompanyStorage.java (the other class)

```
abstract class CompanyStorage extends Context {
    private ArrayList<String> companyList;

    protected CompanyStorage() throws JSONException {
        companyList = get();
    }


    ArrayList<String> get() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject companyData = new JSONObject();
        ArrayList<String> companyList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Open data.json and convert to JSONObject
        String json = OpenFileAsString("data.json");
        try {
            companyData = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return json array as ArrayList
        if (companyData.getJSONArray("companies") != null) {
            for (int i=0;i<companyData.getJSONArray("companies").length();i++){
                companyList.add(companyData.getJSONArray("companies").getString(i));
            }
        }
        return companyList;
    }


    public String OpenFileAsString(String filename) {
        try {
            InputStream stream = getAssets().open( filename );
            int size = stream.available();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
            stream.read(bytes);
            stream.close();

            return new String( bytes );

        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            Log.i("GuiFormData", "IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

==> Here it says that if get() is static, OpenFileAsString() should also be static, but then it gives an error, because getAssets() can't be in a static method.

Does anyone know what I should do? I'm fairly new to Java and application design..

Comment: then create CompanyStorage  object and make get() method public and simply access it by CompanyStorage  object https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Comment: If I do that, it asks to implement all the methods...

Answer (score 0):

Try to put static at the get() and OpenFileAsString(String filename) methods header and use context.getAssets() instead of getAssets()

Comment: Ok, but how do I properly create a new Context?

Comment: You don't create it, you put it to your method's parameters - `get(Context context)` and `OpenFileAsString(Context context, String filename)`, then you update all calls to these methods to pass Context

Comment: I've tried a lot now, also what you're saying, and nothing seems to work. It keeps telling me that get() should be static...

Comment: It says: `Non Static method 'get(android.content.Context)' cannot be referenced from a static context.`

Comment: try defining the methods as static -  static get(Context context)